# Return account balances only if a date is greater than 30 days in the past

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table `accounts` that has customer ID's in column `account_ID` with multiple account balances per ID in column `account_balance`. There are also multiple statement dates per ID, column `account_statement_date`.

I need to return the ID and account balance if the account balance is greater than $50.00 and if the most recent statement date is greater than 30 days in the past.

This will return the ID and account balance if the account balance is greater than $50.00:

```
select account_ID, sum(account_balance)
from accounts
where account_balance > 50
group by account_ID
```

How do I refine the query to only return the ID and account balance if the account balance is greater than $50.00 and if the most recent statement date is greater than 30 days in the past?

Comment: Is the account balance equal to the `SUM()` of values in the `account_balance` column for a particular value of `account_id`? I would think an account balance would not need to be aggregated.

Comment: So you only want the most recent account_balance given account. And you only want those when the most recent balance is more than $50 and 30 days have elapsed since the statement date?

Comment: What is the layout of your table? Is the account_statement_date a column inside account? is it on a different table?

Comment: Please see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639774/57611) and provide sample data (similar to mine but accurately representing your data) with the right answer for that data set. Try to provide "tricky data" that helps rule out edge cases to more clearly define the required business rules. Feel free to copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `having` clause to your query:

```
select account_ID, sum(account_balance)
from accounts
where account_balance > 50
group by account_ID
having max(account_statement_date) < sysdate - 30;
```

EDIT:

Shankar's comment would seem to be correct.  The following fixes it:

```
select account_ID,
        sum(case when account_balance > 50 then account_balance else 0 end)
from accounts
group by account_ID
having max(account_statement_date) < sysdate - 30;
```

Comment: This wont work because in the question he says one account can have multiple balances. So when you do where account_balance > 50, it could eliminate few rows. For eg, if acc1 has 2 balances, 25 and 30, the total is 55, which needs to get displayed, but when using the above query will eliminate the acc1 totally.

Comment: I think you want `<` in your `HAVING` clause ("greater than 30 days in the past" per OP).

Comment: @DavidFaber . . . I found "greater than 30 days in the past" to be ambiguous when I first read it (is that a *date* later than 30 days in the past, or is that a "date" earlier than 30 days in the past).  On re-reading it, it seems like my original interpretation was not correct.

Comment: Yes, it *does* seem a bit ambiguous ... "more than 30 days" would probably be a better way to phrase it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you should be summing the account balance in aggregate.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT account_id, account_balance, account_statement_date
         , MAX(account_statement_date) OVER ( PARTITION BY account_id ) AS max_statement_date
      FROM accounts
) WHERE account_balance > 50
    AND account_statement_date = max_statement_date
    AND max_statement_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE-30);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data looks like this:

```
account_ID  account_statement_date  account_balance
1529        2014-12-01              $40.00
1529        2015-01-01              $60.00
1529        2015-02-01              $65.00 -- < 30 days
2647        2014-12-01              $20.00
2647        2015-01-01              $25.00 -- > 30 days but < $50
3198        2014-12-01              $10.00
3198        2015-01-01              $50.00 -- > 30 days and >= $50
```

And the correct answer when run on `2015-02-01` is:

```
account_ID  account_statement_date  account_balance
3198        2015-01-01              $50.00
```

then I think the query you want might look something like this:

```
SELECT
   a.account_ID,
   a.account_statement_date,
   a.account_balance
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY account_ID ORDER BY account_statement_date DESC) AS latest,
         account_ID,
         account_statement_date,
         account_balance
      FROM
         accounts
   ) AS a
WHERE
   a.account_statement_date < sysdate - 30
   AND a.latest = 1
   AND a.account_balance >= 50
;
```

But, if your data looks like this:

```
account_ID  account_balance_date account_statement_date  account_balance
1529        2014-12-10           2015-01-01              $40.00
1529        2015-12-16           2015-01-01              $60.00
1529        2015-01-10           2015-02-01              $30.00
1529        2015-01-19           2015-02-01              $65.00 -- < 30 days
2647        2014-12-25           2015-01-01              $20.00
2647        2014-12-30           2015-01-01              $25.00 -- > 30 days
2647        2014-01-02           NULL                    $75.00
2647        2014-01-15           NULL                    $20.00 -- but < $50
3198        2014-12-14           2015-01-01              $20.00
3198        2014-12-30           2015-01-01              $25.00 -- > 30 days
3198        2014-01-09           NULL                    $20.00
3198        2014-01-22           NULL                    $50.00 -- and >= $50!
```

And the correct answer when run on `2015-02-01` is:

```
account_ID  last_account_statement_date  last_account_balance
3198        2015-01-01                   $50.00
```

then I think the query you want might look something like this:

```
SELECT
   a.account_ID,
   a.account_balance AS last_account_balance,
   (
      SELECT Max(account_statement_date)
      FROM accounts a3
      WHERE
         a1.account_ID = a3.account_ID
         AND account_statement_date IS NOT NULL
   ) AS last_statement_date
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY account_ID ORDER BY account_balance_date DESC) AS latest,
         account_ID,
         account_balance_date,
         account_statement_date,
         account_balance
      FROM
         accounts
   ) AS a
 WHERE
    a.latest = 1 -- the most recent balance by account_balance_date
    AND a.account_balance >= 50
    AND ( -- this clause is optional and may aid or harm performance
       a.account_statement_date IS NULL
       OR a.account_statement_date < sysdate - 30
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS ( -- no statement in the last 30 days
       SELECT *
       FROM
          accounts AS a2
       WHERE
          a.account_ID = a2.accountID
          AND a2.account_statement_date >= sysdate - 30
    )
;
```

I'm suspicious of the 30 days part--it may be that the right calculation will involve some date math about "one month" from the previous statement date, with known rules for deciding what that means for months with a different number of days.

Comment: You mentioned it in comments, but you never actually check the $50 requirement anywhere in there.

Comment: Thanks! Is that better? I was rushed at the end and missed that.

Comment: I just thought I would mention it since OP might not be clear where exactly to add it. And I suppose that technically OP asked for strictly greater than rather than greater than or equal but that's not significant in my book.

Comment: Here's a bigger thing I just noticed: no reason for a subquery if we already know that a.account_balance date is the latest statement date.

Comment: I considered adding something like that the first time, but I didn't like introducing a complicated OR condition. I've put it in now with a notation on its optional nature. The "greater than $50" I took the same as the colloquial phrase "over 18" which means the person is *at least* 18.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you..

```
select * from
(select account_ID, sum(account_balance) bal, max(account_statement_date) st_date
from accounts
group by account_ID) tab1
where tab1.bal > 50 and tab1.st_date > (sysdate - 30)
```